# Unit-testing Electron-React app with Jest, TypeError: Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, electron, jestjs

Implementing `jest` snapshot tests in an `electron-react` app i run into an error:

> TypeError: Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null'.

**I can't find any way to get the tests working when a `React` component contains `electron` navite elements such as `shell, Menu, MenuItem`.**

I have tried passing `shell` as a prop, as in the commented code in **Home.spec.j**s, but there is no change.

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { remote } from 'electron';
const { shell } = remote;

export default class Home extends Component {
    openLink() {
        shell.openExternal('https://www.facebook.com')
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => this.openLink()}>
                    Open External
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Home.spec.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import Home from '../../app/components/Home';

// import { remote } from 'electron'
// const { shell } = remote;

describe('Counter component', () => {
    it('should render snapshot', () => {
        const component = renderer.create(
            <Home />
            //<Home shell={shell} />
        )
        const tree = component.toJSON()
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
    })
});
```

Comment: Is everything working if you remove all the electron parts from your component?

Comment: Yes, removing electron parts tests run ok.

Comment: Okey. Wouldn't it be better to keep the Electron parts outside of the React components? You can either use dispatchers and listen for events or just listen for the webviews `new-window` event to run `openExternal`.

Comment: That's a great idea! Don't know how i never thought of that :-D

Comment: Glad to hear that you like it. Can you mark my answer as correct so other people can be helped? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the separation in your application I would propose that you don't mix up Electron and React parts. Depending on your application, two solutions could be:

1. Use dispatchers to send events from your React components and run the actions from pure JS functions.
2. Listen for [new-window](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/#event-new-window) event on the WebView you're rendering, and from that event run `openExternal`

[Example from Electron](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/#event-new-window):

```
const {shell} = require('electron')
const webview = document.querySelector('webview')

webview.addEventListener('new-window', (e) => {
  const protocol = require('url').parse(e.url).protocol
  if (protocol === 'http:' || protocol === 'https:') {
    shell.openExternal(e.url)
  }
})
```